# Pop-up is showing when i clear the text area . Want to show only for numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I am checking the form validation where the text area can't contain any numbers. But when I delete any text from the text area(when it is empty) the pop-up is showing again. I want to show the pop-up only for numbers.

```js
function validate() {
  var re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if (re.test(document.getElementById('student_name').value)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Numbers are not allowed.');
  }
  var element = document.getElementById('student_name');
  element.value = element.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/, "");
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <tr>
      <td width="40%" colspan="2">Name of the student<br>

      </td>
      <td width="60%" colspan="2">
        <p align="left"><input type="text" name="Student_Name" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="student_name" oninput="validate()">
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: one way which may work is just making an array of the numbers and then simply looping through the string to see if it contains any number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to change your regex from `/^[A-Za-z]+$/` to `/^[A-Za-z]*$/`.**

Notice the difference between the `+` and `*` character,

- `+` matches **one or more** characters, so **won't match an empty string.**
- Whereas `*` matches **zero or more** characters, **so will match an empty string.**

```js
function validate() {
  var re = /^[A-Za-z]*$/;
  if (re.test(document.getElementById('student_name').value)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Numbers are not allowed.');
  }
  var element = document.getElementById('student_name');
  element.value = element.value.replace(/^[A-Za-z]*$/, "");
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <tr>
      <td width="40%" colspan="2">Name of the student<br>

      </td>
      <td width="60%" colspan="2">
        <p align="left"><input type="text" name="Student_Name" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="student_name" oninput="validate()">
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work? I'm sure there's a better option, though.

```js
function validate() {
  var re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if (re.test(document.getElementById('student_name').value) || document.getElementById('student_name').value === "" ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Numbers are not allowed.');
  }
  var element = document.getElementById('student_name');
  element.value = element.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/, "");
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <tr>
      <td width="40%" colspan="2">Name of the student<br>

      </td>
      <td width="60%" colspan="2">
        <p align="left"><input type="text" name="Student_Name" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="student_name" oninput="validate()">
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. change the digits regex pattern to match on digits instead
2. change the if statement according to the regex
3. evaluate the cleanup with the same regex

full code:

```js
 function validate()
        {
            var re = /\d/;
            if(!re.test(document.getElementById('student_name').value))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Numbers are not allowed.');
            }
            var element=document.getElementById('student_name');
            element.value=element.value.replace(re,"");
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <tr>
    <td width="40%" colspan="2">Name of the student<br>
    
    </td>
    <td width="60%" colspan="2">
    <p align="left"><input type="text" name="Student_Name" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="student_name" oninput="validate()">
    </p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
</body>
```